# How to call a function after client push inlinekeyboardbutton?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I need to call `Add()` function after the client push the `inlinekeyboardbutton` with `callback_data` 1.

How can I do that?

```
query = update.callback_query

    if (query.data == '1'):
        # call Add() function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use callback query handlers

```
from telebot import *

bot = TeleBot(token)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda query: 1 == query.data)
def add(query):
    pass
```